# Retriving challenge element from XML string

Tags: xml, c#-3.0

m trying to retrieve challenge element from below Xml,

i,m using below code

```
string Xmlstring = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><stream:stream id=\"3DAC47EA\" from=\"chat.facebook.com\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\" xml:lang=\"en\"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\"><mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features><challenge xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">dmVyc2lvbj0xJm1ldGhvZD1hdXRoLnhtcHBfbG9naW4mbm9uY2U9QjNBOUU4NzJFQUJGNkQ5RDM0RTZDNjgzMjkyMTBGOEQ=</challenge>";

XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.LoadXml(Xmlstring);
```

i get Error saying "Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: stream:stream. Line 1, position 510."

Answer (score 2):

Error tells it all, the xml you are trying to load is invalid and Stream element is not closed 
Your xml

```
<stream:stream id=\"3DAC47EA\" from=\"chat.facebook.com\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\" xml:lang=\"en\">

<stream:features>

<mechanisms xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">

<mechanism>
X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM
</mechanism>

<mechanism>
DIGEST-MD5
</mechanism>

</mechanisms>

</stream:features>

<challenge xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">
dmVyc2lvbj0xJm1ldGhvZD1hdXRoLnhtcHBfbG9naW4mbm9uY2U9QjNBOUU4NzJFQUJGNkQ5RDM0RTZDNjgzMjkyMTBGOEQ=
</challenge>
```

Your document lacks a root node, and the "stream" element is not closed. Correcting the xml document will fix the error.

The stream element must be fixed as

```
<stream:stream id=\"3DAC47EA\" from=\"chat.facebook.com\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\" xml:lang=\"en\">
 ...
</stream:stream>
```

And your other elements comes inside the stream element **if** it is the root for your document.

As you are taking it as a string in your code example (in your question)
you can just append the missing stream as below and the pass it to the xmlreader as usual,

**(*Note: this is only a workaround based on your example, but I donot understand how you are getting invalid XML as a response from a server.)**

```
Xmlstring = Xmlstring + "</stream:stream>";
```

This makes the xml valid and you can get load it to the document as usual.

Comment: I,m getting this as a response from facebook server , so do i need to modify the string element and insert stream tag, or is there any other way to get the value of challenge element